# How can I use custom HTML buttons to call a Mapbox GL JS Draw Polygon function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to build a custom controller for a map using Mapbox GL JS which includes a Draw polygon functionality. But when I wish to include the Draw polygon as per the Mapbox Documentation, it shows a menu on top right of the screen.

[This is how it looks whenever I add the JS shown in https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-draw/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3LbS.png)

This is the JS code which works Mapbox GL JS documentation has provided

```
var draw = new MapboxDraw({
// Instead of showing all the draw tools, show only the line string and delete tools
displayControlsDefault: false,
controls: {
    line_string: true,
    polygon: true,
    point: true,
    trash: true
}

});


// Add the draw tool to the map
map.addControl(draw);
```

I want to build a custom button which does the same function of allowing me to draw over a map.

[I wish to use this button and it should open the draw cursor similar to when I click on draw function in their default menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rB0kz.png)

How can I going about doing this?

Answer (score 5):

You can apply the drawing mode using draw.changeMode('draw_polygon'). This would trigger the same event as the original button would do. Therefore you can get rid of that.

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function () {
    draw.changeMode('draw_polygon');

}
```

Comment: But this way the original control is visible too!

Comment: @Alexander even if you remove the:
 controls: {line_string: true,polygon: true, point: true, trash: true} lines from your code?

Comment: Yep. Even for plain constuctor initialization. There is approach to patch the original MapboxDraw and add custom buttons. But it was such a pain that eventually I've sticked to the original MapboxDraw and decided to live with it :)

Comment: works for me if I set 'false' for controls explicitly
```controls: {
            polygon: false,
            trash: false
        }```

Comment: Good solution, but getting below issue when I tried to draw the polygon from sub functional component(outside of the mapview). Is there any way to do this?
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'changeMode')

Comment: @user1173465 can you create a JS Bin/codepen example on this?